# Using XSLT, how to translate &quot; with &apos;

Tags: xslt

Using XSLT, I need to create a CSV report while processing an XML document.
During the procedure, I check if one of the column will contain a comma (,); if yes I put quotes around the value. My problem is that the value may already contains " ("), which will confuse the CSV format.

In XSLT, how can I replace all the " (") in a string with ' (')
I tried using fn:translate:

```
<xsl:value-of select="**fn:translate(., '&quot;', '@apos;')**"/>
```

is rejected because it sees it as

```
<xsl:value-of select="fn:translate(., '"', **'''**)"/>
```

Any suggestion?

Current XSLT

```
<xsl:function name="cm:forCSV">
    <xsl:param name="node" as="item()*"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains($node, ',')">
        <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$node instance of xs:string">
            <xsl:value-of select="fn:normalize-space(**fn:translate($node, '&quot;', '&apos;')**)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            ...
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="contains($node, ',')">
        <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:function>
```

Sample data:
<sample value=**"test"**>an example**,** to be saved in a column

Expected:
<sample value=**'test'**>an example**,** to be saved in a column

To have in my CSV

..., "<sample value=**'test'**>an example**,** to be saved in a column", ...

Comment: In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: You have some strange asterisks in your code blocks, which confused me. I think you may have been expecting them to produce a highlighting effect in your post, but they don't. It would be good if you would remove them, because they are going to confuse other people too.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using XSLT 2.0 or higher, you can escape apostrophes  and quotes by doubling them:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate($string, '&quot;', '&apos;&apos;')" />
```

From the [XPath 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#doc-xpath-EscapeApos) specification:

> If the literal is delimited by apostrophes, two adjacent apostrophes within the literal are interpreted as a single apostrophe. Similarly, if the literal is delimited by quotation marks, two adjacent quotation marks within the literal are interpreted as one quotation mark.

---

In XSLT 1.0, you would have to do:

```
<xsl:variable name="apos" select='"&apos;"'/>
<xsl:value-of select="translate($string, '&quot;', $apos)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option for referring to quotes, apostrophes, ampersands, etc, in XSLT is to use the `codepoints-to-string` function to generate them:

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="translate(., codepoints-to-string(34), codepoints-to-string(39)"/>
```

... or define variables using `'` to enclose `"` and vice versa:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="quote" select='"'/>
<xsl:variable name="apos" select="'"/>
```

... or using a text node to define the value:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="quote">"</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
```

... and then refer to the variables:

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="translate(., $quote, $apos)"/>
```

But actually I'd suggest that rather than translate `"` to `'`, you could use a regular expression to find `"` characters in the input string and double them (i.e. replace each `"` with `""`) which is the standard way to include `"` characters in a quoted CSV field.

```xml
<xsl:variable name="quote-regex">/"</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="replace(., $quote-regex, '$1$1')"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

In XPath, you can use single quotes to quote a double quote and vice versa:

```
fn:translate(., '"', "'")
```

When the XPath expression is the `select` attribute of an XML element, you can put it in single quotes and escape the single quotes in the expression as `&apos;`, or similarly put it in double quotes:

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="fn:translate(., '&quot;', &quot;'&quot;)"/>
```